# Show many id's onload of cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'd like to change `display: none` to `display: block` for few divs when app starts. Id's of this divs are stored in localstorage. Every id is new localstorage item. My function, that loads on app start is:

```
function loadStorage() {
 for (var i = 0, l = localStorage.length; i < l; i++) {
 document.getElementById(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))).style.display = "block"
  }
}
```

When i use my app in browser on my laptop, it works. When I load app on android app, only one id is shown. Any idea, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. estimate how may IDs on average you will use.
2. create (by hand) that many IDs.
3. *display:block* all the IDs on a single page.
4. try that page on your mobile device.

*NOTE:* just because something works in your browser, it is no guarantee that it will work on mobile. The development cycle for mobile browsers is very slow - especially those use with Cordova/Phonegap. You may also consider using [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) or [CocoonJS](https://www.ludei.com/landing/cocoonjs-phonegap/), or one of the [other alternatives](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/webview-alternatives.md).